# .NET Core open ClientBase connection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm currently in the process of moving an application from .NET Framework to .NET Core and I'm running into an issue with opening a connection.

The .NET Core version of System.ServiceModel (System.ServiceModel.Primitives) doesn't contain a definition for Open(), unlike the .NET Framework version.

Methods of System.ServiceModel.ClientBase in

**Core:**

```
 public void Abort();
 public void Close();
 protected virtual TChannel CreateChannel();
 protected T GetDefaultValueForInitialization<T>();
 protected void InvokeAsync();
```

**Framework:**

```
 public void Abort();
 public void Close();
 public void DisplayInitializationUI();
 public void Open();
 protected T GetDefaultValueForInitialization<T>();
 protected void InvokeAsync();
```

This makes it a little awkward when I have to open a connection, any help on how you do it in .NET Core is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question? How to use WCF? ClientBase is a *base* class, not meant to be called directly, so what is the actual code you want to use? Which .NET Core version?

Comment: BTW it's *not* typical to use the WCF primitives directly. Using WCF in .NET Old and .NET Core is pretty similar and the generated proxies almost identical. [ICommunicationObject.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1.system-servicemodel-icommunicationobject-open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) is available in both versions, through explicit interface implementation.

Comment: how you open connections greatly differs between .netcore and .net.  I dont think a convert is going to work.  You will need to recreate the project and convert things over your self.  Because of the different frameworks they use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the [System.ServiceModel.Primitives](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Primitives) nuget package